# SQL SELECT Query use for search

Tags: php, mysql, logic

I have three variables:

```
$school
$class
$subject
```

And a search String `$searchquery`

I want to search my database for the rows that match the Search Query... Currently I am using this:

```
$searchquery = str_replace(" ","|",$searchquery);
$sql = "
    SELECT * FROM filedetails 
    WHERE school RLIKE '$searchquery' 
        OR class RLIKE '$searchquery' 
        OR subject RLIKE '$searchquery'";
```

Now, how this works, Suppose I enter `Mathematics Class X`. It converts the string into `Mathematics|Class|X` which is fine and search the Database and prints the results...
But there is one error:

It is printing all the rows which have either Mathematics or Class or X in them, so my output includes all the Classes of all Schools of Mathematics and All Subjects of All Schools of Class X...

Whereas I want it to show me All Schools having Mathematics and Class X...

P.S. - I have tried using AND instead of OR, but now I get empty result because no School Matches my Query String...

Comment: Your answer is in your question `Mathematics and Class X...`.. use AND instead of OR

Comment: Here you go... ;) @raveenanigam

Comment: hi what is the use of your three variables

Comment: **WARNING**: This example looks full of [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: You need to specify better what kind of result you want. Does your 'querystring' always have 3 parts? Which parts needs to matched against which fields (school, class, subject) ?

Comment: Yeah, I will do that but my main problem at this moment is about the logic... @tadman

Comment: `RLIKE` is brutally slow on non-trivial amounts of data. Have you tried using  [full-text indexing and search methods](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html)? Making a regular expression to execute requires two levels of escaping, it's a hassle that's best avoided.

Comment: No, my 'querystring' doesn't always have three parts, It can have only one, or two or three or even more than that, Suppose I search Methodist High School Class X, It should show me all Subjects of the same... Hope this helps... @MarkusLaire

Comment: So if querystring is 'Methodist High School Class X', you probably want to match 'Methodist High School' against school. But what is the meaning of 'Class' and 'X'?

Comment: @MarkusLaire, I want to match Class X to against class Column, Class X is how we say 10th grade (The X is Roman Number of 10)...

Comment: @tadman... FULLTEXT is also of no good use, and Secondly, my database will be like 500 rows maximum...

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want an intelligent search which automatically understand which words (or combination of words like 'Class X' or 'Methodist High School') needs to be matched against which fields, using AND logic. This is not trivial to do.

Comment: Yes, I know, but how...

Comment: This kind of search can't be done without much better specification of what kind of queries you really want. If you want also partial matches it can become impossible to do. Instead you should really consider using three separate querystrings, one for each field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing is first make different 2-D Arrays of all the data searches and then take their intersection, so this will give the common row which matches all the keywords...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM filedetails";
      $query = mysql_query($sql);
      $array1 = array();
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
      {
           $array1[] = $row;
      }
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM filedetails WHERE school RLIKE '$searchquery'";
      $query = mysql_query($sql);
      $array2 = array();
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
      {
           $array2[] = $row;
      }
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM filedetails WHERE subject RLIKE '$searchquery'";
      $query = mysql_query($sql);
      $array3 = array();
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
      {
           $array3[] = $row;
      }
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM filedetails WHERE class RLIKE '$searchquery'";
      $query = mysql_query($sql);
      $array4 = array();
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
      {
           $array4[] = $row;
      }
```

Now, what this code is doing that it is searching individually for every field and making separate result for each Query of each field, now We will be taking Intersection of the arrays so as to get the common row having the keywords

But there is one problem, suppose the `$searchquery` contains Details about School and Class, but no information about Subject, then the `$array3` will be null, as the query will result NULL, then we need to consider handling null arrays which have been solved in [Another Question Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585066/php-intersect-array-but-not-null-array)...

Hope this helps... :)