# PHP Intersect Array but not NULL Array

Tags: php, arrays, logic

I have five 2-D Arrays, (You can assume it like five spreadsheets), I want to take the intersection of the five (I want the common rows of all five in a new spreadsheet) but now I find out that one of the array is a NULL Array, (I find that instead of a spreadsheet, it's just a blank piece of paper), so now I want to ignore it and Intersect the rest of the Arrays... Please suggest a method of doing that...

P.S. - I know it is against the property of intersection because we all know that Intersection of anything with NULL is NULL, but that is not what I want...

P.S. - I also don't know how many Arrays can be empty, I just assumed it to be 1 as an Example, It can be 2, 3, 4 or Even 5... Yes, If it is 5,  then returning NULL is perfect but not in any other case... Suppose if 4 Arrays are NULL, then It should return the 5th Array...

Language Used : PHP

Comment: Just filter the array after getting the intersection.

Comment: If possible, can you please tell me.. Because intersection with NULL will give me NULL, so **What will I filter** ?

Comment: @Rizier123 Hardly constructive, is it?

Comment: @Rizier123 You're suggesting to filter ***after*** intersecting, while OP is explicitly saying that intersecting on an empty array will yield *nothing*, which is what he tries to prevent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and a custom implementation of [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check if your array is null

**Solution** :

```
$array1 = array(6,  10, 11, 12);
$array2 = array(6, 741, 18, 9, 110, 11, 12);
$array3 = array(8, 10, 11, 20);
$array4 = null;
$array5 = array(9, 10, 11, 12);


function in_array_custom($item, $array)
{
    if($array === null){
        return true;
    }
    return in_array($item, $array);
}

function intersect($item)
{
    global $array2;
    global $array3;
    global $array4;
    global $array5;
    return in_array_custom($item, $array2) && in_array_custom($item, $array3) && in_array_custom($item, $array4) && in_array_custom($item, $array5);
}

print_r(array_filter($array1, "intersect"));
```

[Live example](https://3v4l.org/N29fU)

I share the global solution :

```
<?php

$arrays = array(
    array(6,  10, 11, 12),
    array(6, 741, 18, 9, 110, 11, 12),
    array(8, 10, 11, 20),
    null,
    array(9, 10, 11, 12)
);

function in_array_custom($item, $array)
{
    if($array === null){
        return true;
    }
    return in_array($item, $array);
}

function in_arrays($item, $arrays)
{
    foreach($arrays as $array)
    {
        if(!in_array_custom($item, $array)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function intersect($item)
{
    global $arrays;
    return in_arrays($item, $arrays);
}

print_r(array_filter($arrays[0], "intersect"));
```

[Live example](https://3v4l.org/7ZrAr)

---

Here, there is one little issue, that If the first array (`$array1`) is null, then the code will not work, but that issue can be resolved by taking `$array1` as a Union of all the SIX Arrays, (5 Arrays and 1 Union Array), And the Data is shifted to the next array, i.e `$array2` now holds the data of `$array1`, `$array3 = $array2` and so on...

P.S. - Union of Arrays can be done like this `$array1 = $array2 + $array3 + $array4 + $array5 + $array6;`